# One mysql database per user with thousands of users

Tags: android, mysql, synchronization

I have an Android app and i want to allow my users to sync their local sqlite db with server.Since i have thousands of user's how should i set up my MySql database on server?As i see it there are two approaches,

1) One database per user plus one database to store user's credentials.Is this even possible since there will be thousands of different databases on server?

2) One database that holds all user's data.I was thinking i could add a field (user_id) on each table that identifies a user.I don't like though the idea that all user's data will be on the same table!!!

What's the best approach for my case?Is there something different i could try?

Comment: Of course option 2!

Answer (score 0):

One database that holds all user's data.I was thinking i could add a field (user_id) on each table that identifies a user.I don't like though the idea that all user's data will be on the same table!!!